# Set category name for bean fields in PropertySheet JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx, propertysheet

ContolsFX example for `PropertySheet` have several options. First, create a bean with beaninfo. In this case I can't set category for each field in `PropertySheet`. I can choose only between basic and expert categories. Second option is to use `Map`, where I can set category for each field. But I want to use beans. Is it possible to set category for bean fields?

```
public class SampleBeanBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {

    private static final BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = new BeanDescriptor(SampleBeanBeanInfo.class);
    private static PropertyDescriptor[] propDescriptors;

    static {
        beanDescriptor.setDisplayName("Sample Bean");
    }

    @Override
    public BeanDescriptor getBeanDescriptor() {
        return beanDescriptor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefaultPropertyIndex() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        if (propDescriptors == null) {
            propDescriptors = new PropertyDescriptor[5];
            try {
                CustomPropertyDescriptor cdp = new CustomPropertyDescriptor("id", SampleBean.class, "getId", "setId");
                cdp.setDisplayName("Id");
                cdp.setEditable(false);
                propDescriptors[0] = cdp;
                propDescriptors[1] = new PropertyDescriptor("firstName", SampleBean.class, "getFirstName", "setFirstName");
                propDescriptors[1].setDisplayName("First Name");
                propDescriptors[2] = new PropertyDescriptor("lastName", SampleBean.class, "getLastName", "setLastName");
                propDescriptors[2].setDisplayName("Last Name");
                propDescriptors[3] = new PropertyDescriptor("address", SampleBean.class, "getAddress", "setAddress");
                propDescriptors[3].setDisplayName("Address");
                propDescriptors[3].setPropertyEditorClass(PopupPropertyEditor.class);
                propDescriptors[4] = new PropertyDescriptor("hiddenValue", SampleBean.class, "getHiddenValue", "setHiddenValue");
                propDescriptors[4].setDisplayName("Hidden Value");
                propDescriptors[4].setHidden(true);
            } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return propDescriptors;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, i found that categories are hardcoded and could not be changed when we are using `beans`. So you should use your custom `PropertySheet.Item` implementation. In this case we can set any category name for properties. Check out official example in `controlsFX` project how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
propDescriptors[i].setValue(org.controlsfx.property.BeanProperty.CATEGORY_LABEL_KEY, "Your category name");
```

Comment: We usually prefer more explanation, not just a code dump. What is the key thing of your solution?

Comment: Simply according to the source code of BeanProperty.java:  @Override public String getCategory() {
        String category = (String) this.beanPropertyDescriptor.getValue(BeanProperty.CATEGORY_LABEL_KEY);